# How to hide the bottom action bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I set "android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" in AndroidManifest.xml.
Therefore, if there is no enough room for the device, the action bar will be split into two parts.

Sometime, I want to hide the action bar by calling **getActionBar().hide()**. But it will leave an ugly white space in the bottom. How can I get rid of it?

I tried to call **getActivity().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY)**, but it would block my webview content.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: So you want to hide just the bottom bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a simple work, simply use OverLay. use this in your style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

or if you want to do it by programmatically, just past it before your setContentView() function

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

and give some transparency, so it won't hide the web content. just read the documentation for the style

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html

Comment: I think he wants to hide just the bottom bar. Your solution will hide both top and bottom, right?

Comment: Yes,but overlay with transparency is the best choice. Otherwise he has to add custom bottom bar. lil time consuming too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `android:uiOptions` from `<application>` or `<activity>` elements from the AndroidManifest. Also, remove the `android.support.UI_OPTIONS`  for activity that need in the AndroidManifest.

Answer (score -1):

the split bar can only be hidden with api 11 for the other i tried on my tablet right now and 
it continue to be here on the screen, my tablet have android 4 api >10 then split bar must be taken into count when designing a layout example:
for games  touch screen like tablets or phone without harwdware key ,the thouch event x,y must be trasformed to y=y+height of the split bar, becouse the size of the window is fullscreen - splitbar  and that make  a lot of difference if you have graphical interface drawed with canvas ,that mean you must check if the touch is iniside a rectagle  of a screen button.
and use dp pixel and not pure pixel ,all drawing maust use dp converted pixel cordiantes  for make sure that have same coridanate system on the screen and on the canvas
px = dp *(dpi * default dpi)
deafult dpi is 160pdi screen medium pixel resolution